# Testing if a pandas DataFrame exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my code, I have several variables which can either contain a pandas DataFrame or nothing at all.  Let's say I want to test and see if a certain DataFrame has been created yet or not.  My first thought would be to test for it like this:

```
if df1:
    # do something
```

However, that code fails in this way:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Fair enough.  Ideally, I would like to have a presence test that works for either a DataFrame or Python None.

Here is one way this can work:

```
if not isinstance(df1, type(None)):
    # do something
```

However, testing for type is really slow.

```
t = timeit.Timer('if None: pass')
t.timeit()
# approximately 0.04
t = timeit.Timer('if isinstance(x, type(None)): pass', setup='x=None')
t.timeit()
# approximately 0.4
```

Ouch.  Along with being slow, testing for NoneType isn't very flexible, either.

A different solution would be to initialize `df1` as an empty DataFrame, so that the type would be the same in both the null and non-null cases.  I could then just test using `len()`, or `any()`, or something like that.  Making an empty DataFrame seems kind of silly and wasteful, though.

Another solution would be to have an indicator variable: `df1_exists`, which is set to False until `df1` is created.  Then, instead of testing `df1`, I would be testing `df1_exists`.  But this doesn't seem all that elegant, either.

Is there a better, more Pythonic way of handling this issue?  Am I missing something, or is this just an awkward side effect all the awesome things about pandas?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

***Option 1*** (my preferred option)

#### This is @Ami Tavory's

***Please select his answer if you like this approach***

It is very idiomatic python to initialize a variable with `None` then check for `None` prior to doing something with that variable.

```
df1 = None

if df1 is not None:
    print df1.head()
```

---

***Option 2***

However, setting up an empty dataframe isn't at all a bad idea.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

if not df1.empty:
    print df1.head()
```

---

***Option 3***

Just try it.

```
try:
    print df1.head()
# catch when df1 is None
except AttributeError:
    pass
# catch when it hasn't even been defined
except NameError:
    pass
```

---

#### Timing

***When `df1` is in initialized state or doesn't exist at all***

[image]

***When `df1` is a dataframe with something in it***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), list('ABCDE'), list('abcde'))
df1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add timings?

Answer (score 64):

> In my code, I have several variables which can either contain a pandas DataFrame or nothing at all

The Pythonic way of indicating "nothing" is via `None`, and for checking "not nothing" via

```
if df1 is not None:
    ...
```

I am not sure how critical time is here, but since you measured things:

```
In [82]: t = timeit.Timer('if x is not None: pass', setup='x=None')

In [83]: t.timeit()
Out[83]: 0.022536039352416992

In [84]: t = timeit.Timer('if isinstance(x, type(None)): pass', setup='x=None')

In [85]: t.timeit()
Out[85]: 0.11571192741394043
```

So checking that something `is not None`, is also faster than the `isinstance` alternative.

Comment: My preferred answer.

Comment: `df1` must be defined, though, hence the need of `df1 = None` as in piRSquared’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataframe is stored as a dictionary value, you could test for its existence this way:

```
import pandas as pd

d = dict()
df = pd.DataFrame()

d['df'] = df

## the 'None' is default but including it for the example
if d.get('df', None) is not None:
    ## get df shape
    print(df.shape)
else:
    print('no df here')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try %who_ls DataFrame ?
It outputs a list with all the defined DataFrames.
Then you can check if it contains an element named as the df you are looking for.

```py
listdf=%who_ls DataFrame
if 'df1' in listdf: print("df1 exists!")
```

This still will not tell you if it's empty or not, only that it exists.

You can use %who_ls for other types of elements, too.