# Python recursive function stuck in infinite loop despite Try statement

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I want to write a simple function that prints out a row of a pandas dataframe.  If the dataframe has already been loaded into memory, I don't want to reload it.  If it has not been loaded into memory when the function is called for the first time, I want to load it.

I am using a Try statement to test whether the dataframe exists ([Testing if a pandas DataFrame exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337115/testing-if-a-pandas-dataframe-exists)).  The alternative options for doing this produce NameError as the DF has not been initialised to None or empty.

```
global dfIndices

def getSeriesInfo(seriesCode,verbose=False):
    try:
        if verbose:
            print(dfIndices.loc[seriesCode])
        else:
            print(dfIndices.loc[seriesCode]['Data Item Description'])
    # catch when it hasn't even been defined
    except NameError:
        print('I am here.')
        dfIndices = pd.read_excel(dirAppData+'Indicies.xlsx')
        dfIndices.set_index('Series ID',inplace=True)
        getSeriesInfo(seriesCode,verbose)

getSeriesInfo('A2304402X')
```

Assuming I have not already loaded the dfIndicies dataframe, I would expect when first calling the function, that the Try statement would fail, the dataframe would be loaded, the function called again, the Try passed and the function stop exceuting.

Instead, I get an infinite loop.

So that I can learn something, why doesn't this work as expected and what should I do differently?

Thanks

Comment: Because you have to put `global dfIndices` within the function

Comment: In any case, this isn't particularly good design. You could almost certainly avoid try, global and repeated calls to the same function. Your function also currently does more than one thing (reads a df and the reads from it), which you should almost always avoid. Split in up into two functions: the first reads a df, the second receives that df as a parameter

Comment: Thanks, putting global dfIndicies within the function works. I now remember why:  without it inside the function, there are two dfIndices instances, one global and a second one local to the function.  This helps.

Comment: On the second, why is it bad design?  It really does just do one thing - it prints lookup information about a series from a dataframe.  It just makes sure the df exists if it doesn't already.  What is the benefit of splitting the function into two functions?  read_excel is itself a function and the second part doesn't do much more than that.

Comment: It's called the single responsibility principle (en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You are currently confusing three things: checking if a df exists, reading a df and using a df. Your function that uses the df should be able to assume that the df exists and should only worry about using it (i.e no try except). Another function should read a df, and *pass it into the function that uses it*. You can have yet another function that checks that the df exist. These functions should be callable consecutively instead of being embedded within one another

Comment: Code that follows that principle is easier to understand, easier to maintain / improve, easier to debug and easier to reuse.

Comment: Above "pass it into the function that uses it" should read "you can then pass it's result into the function that uses it". Sorry comment can only be edited for 5 mins

Comment: Thanks Karl.  I like your point that the function should be able to assume that the df exists.  I will recode accordingly.  Appreciate you taking the time to explain.